# How to write in my page Exception Value with Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to know how could a return to my page (and so write it) an Exception Value when it is raised.
For instance now I'm doing this:

```
try:
    user.save()
except:
    err_msg="An error verified during user adding process. Please repeate the procedure"
return render_to_response('staff.html', {'m':m, 'err_msg':err_msg})
```

I would like to be more clear to the user and told him what error is raised.

Answer (score 0):

You should not show the actual error message to the user. That is bad in terms of security. What you have just done is fine. But you should figure out what was the reason for failure by printing actual error message for debugging purpose:

```
try:
    user.save()
except Exception, e:
    print e.message # print actual error message and figure out what went wrong
    err_msg="An error verified during user adding process. Please repeate the procedure"
return render_to_response('staff.html', {'m':m, 'err_msg':err_msg})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking, how to capture the *text* of the error message, just capture it and print it:

```
try:
   '2' + 2
except TypeError as e:
   print '{}'.format(e)
```

You can also `print e.message`, but its safer to try and print it directly.

If you don't know what exception is going to be raised, you can use a generic except clause, and then do this:

```
import sys

try:
   '2' + 2
except:
    print sys.exc_info()[1].message
```

However, a generic except clause is not good programming practice.  It is always good to catch exceptions explicitly.

Comment: In your example you have TypeError, in mine not, because I don't know what kind of error i could receive